# Jenkins pay for subscription plugin

Tags: jenkins, plugins

Is there a plugin which will remove a use rights until he pay a subscription fee ?
I know that there is the matrix plugin for user permissions. But I do not know about any subscription fee plugin .

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no Jenkins plugin which does this.

However, Jenkins does come with a simple but effective User Database out of the box which allows you as the administrator to control what each user can actually do.

See documentation [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup)